# wordpress php query by category name

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering to do separate blog pages for separate category posts. What I was able to find was running query by category number, but this is not dynamic enough for me as I would like to run query on page title which is = category name.

Basically on page "events" I would like to display blog posts that are under category named "events"(category name == page title), and so on.

Any insights on how to achieve this would be great. What I tried to do and failed, was:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title()); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>no match<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in forward for any insights, links or notices.

Comment: add the desired category as custom field to the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, never ever use `query_posts`.  It breaks the main query, reruns queries that slows your page, incorrectly sets vital functions used by plugins, functions like `get_queried_object()` and it messes up pagination.

If you need to run custom queries, make use of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

To come to your original issue, the default category parameters don't make use of category names, only slugs and ID's. The slugs are controllable, so you might want to use slugs with the `category_name` parameter.

If you do need to pass category names, then you should use a `tax_query` which do accept names passed to the `terms` parameter

You can pass the following with your parameters

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => 'name of your category',
        'include_children' => false,
    ) ,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `get_post` function.

Do like this:

```
<?php

    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Let me know if you need further help.